# Read binary file one field at a time in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, readfile

I am learning how to handle files in C. When I try to read a binary file, everything runs fine but I get a garbage output.

Here is my code:

```
FILE *ptr;
struct file rec;

ptr=fopen("sample.bin","rb");
while(!feof(ptr))
{
    fread(&rec,sizeof(struct file),1,ptr);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %f, %x, %s, %f, %c, %d, %u, %d, %x, %d, %d, %u, %f\n",
    rec.a, rec.b, rec.c, rec.d, re.e, rec.f,rec.g, rec.h, rec.i, rec.j, rec.k, rec.l,rec.m, rec.n, rec.o, rec.p, rec.q);
}
```

So I am thinking I might need to use more than one `fread()`. Can Someone show me how to use it?

Note: This is how the sample.bin looks like:

```
0000 0000 0101 002f 1000 0000 00f4 0d0a
4540 8f94 e9ff ffff ffff 636c 6f63 6b00
00c0 ece0 3b69 b736 a1ea ffff ffff 2700
0000 0000 8dcb 0cce 0301 7294 cc02 0000
0000 0000 42bf
```

Comment: In addition to needing to know the information in David's answer, you should also be checking the `return` to `fread` so you know whether you have any data to `printf` before you attempt to access a whole lot of uninitialized or garbage values in `rec.a, ... rec.q`.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting the binary file to be decoded by magic. You need to understand the binary file format at the byte level, read in a chunk of it, decode the bytes, and set values appropriately in the structure. Nowhere in your code is there anything that explains what each byte in the file means, and that knowledge is necessary to make sense of the file.